# Drop shadows on iPhone Clock App "Alarm" tab

Tags: iphone, uitableview, graphics

In the clock app that comes with the iPhone there is a tab view for setting alarms. In that view each of the UITableViewCell instances have a drop shadow around them. Does anyone know how to achieve the same effect?

Also it looks like the tab bar at the very bottom has a drop shadow above it as well.

Ideas on how to achieve the same look would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I was wondering how to do that and it just occurred to me to use the UITableView's footer view:

```
myTableView.tableFooterView = myCustomViewWithDropShadowImage;
```

Answer (score 0):

I would guess that there is an extra cell which contains just a background image which is the transparent dropshadow. If it's not a cell (because that might create scrolling weirdness) it is probably an extra view positioned below the bottom cell of the UITableview which - again - simply contains an image of the drop shadow.

Comment: Hmmm... I don't think the extra cell theory would work, but the extra view below the cell would definitely be a possibility. I will try it out tomorrow

Answer (score 0):

Like Thomas said, create a 100% width image (say, 320 x 40px on non-retina devices) and create 4 instances of UIImageView with it. The first, at the top of your main view. The second, at the bottom, and in addition do this:

```
UIImageView* bottomShadow = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"BottmShadow.png"]] 
bottomShadow.transform = CGAffineTransformMakeScale(1, -1);
```

(Flip it vertically)

Then, do the same with the other two, but place them as subviews of the Table View. One of them just outside the first row:

```
CGRect tableTopShadowFrame = tableTopShadow.frame;
tableTopShadowFrame.origin.y = -(tableTopShadowFrame.size.height);
[tableTopShadow setFrame:tableTopShadowFrame];
```

and the other just below the last row (you need to know the height of all the rows together. If your rows are all the same height, it is row height times number of rows).

Finally, you need to set the table's backgroundColor property to transparent

```
tableView.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
```

and possibly set some darkish gray for your main view's background color.